# Grep and regular expressions (consecutive letters)

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to figure out how to list consecutive letters in grep. For example if I wanted to list all words with two consecutive a’s OR i’s OR u’s in one line how would I do this?

From my understanding the command would look something like egrep [a]{2} | egrep [i]{2} | egrep [u]{2}

But what if it's the case that the word has aa and ii or any other combination of the three letters consecutively by twos?

Comment: Grep is not egrep.  Please be more specific in the title.

Comment: Well it kind of is - they're the same program under the hood, but when invoked as `egrep` it just adds the `-E` option. That does change the regular expression syntax a little but it doesn't make a substantial difference in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got in your question is actually three separate commands: it'll search for anything that has `aa`, then pass those results to the next `egrep` which searches for anything that has `ii`, then passes those results to the last `egrep` which searches for `uu`. So you wind up with only those lines that contain all three of the combinations `aa`, `ii`, *and* `uu`.

You'd need to use just *one* `egrep` command, using a regular expression with alternation:

```
egrep 'aa|ii|uu'
```

This will match all lines that contain any of `aa`, `ii`, or `uu`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Regex only works with regular expressions.  You will notice that regular expressions do not have any sort of memory (thus can't say (.*)*2 or something like that).  You're looking for a finite atomota or a turring machine.

Comment: Hm. Well I know for example if I write a command like: egrep '(.)\1(.)\2(.)\3' /usr/share/dict/words
It would show words with sequential consecutive letters, but I'm not able to pick specific ones. I want to find a word that has aa or a word that has ii or uu in it but not necessarily all three at the same time. I don't think this is an impossible task. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Just combine the two ideas: egrep '([aiu])\1'

Comment: Side note: technically when you use backreferences like `\1`, what you have isn't quite a regular expression. (An "irregular expression" I suppose :-P)